# what is msvc_x64_x64 and how is different from msvc_x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, windows-7-x64, visual-studio-2019

I am using visual studio 2019 with cmake project. When opening cmake settings UI in visual studio IDE, it shows a list of toolset for a C++ project.

From the list of toolsets, I have `msvc_x64` and `msvc_x64_x64`. I want to build on native x64, so I can simply select msvc_x64.

But why there is two toolset named x64 and x64_x64?

Is it the same thing or they are maintaining two names for some sort of backward compatibility?

As per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019), I can understand the naming conventions for toolsets such as msvc_x86_x64, amd64, x64_arm etc.. I would like to learn about x64 and x64_x64 and why these two exist?

Is there any difference between two ? If so can I get some documentation about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**msvc_x64**

This toolset is to target x64 with the x86 version of MSVC.

---

**msvc_x64_x64**

This toolset is to target x64 with the x64 version of MSVC.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. it is a bit wired naming though. they could stick to conventions and use msvc_x64_x86. Do you have a link to docs?

Comment: Not my answer, but it is specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=msvc-160)